# Can I use a more pythonic way for my conditional array operations?

Tags: python, numpy

In Python using `numpy` I have to do some iterations over a `numpy` 2D array.
I boiled down the original problem to its essentials:

```
f = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 22, 30, 40, 50, 0], [0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
u = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1],     [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1],   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
x = np.zeros_like(f)

for i in range(1,u.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,u.shape[1]-1):
        if u[i,j] > 0: 
            x[i,j] = u[i,j]*(f[i,j]-f[i,j-1])
        else:
            x[i,j] = -u[i,j]*(f[i,j+1]-f[i,j])
```

In this iteration I have to iterate over all 2D indices.
Is there a more elegant way? If there would be no condition on u I would just write:

```
y = np.zeros_like(f)    

y[1:-1, 1:-1] = u[1:-1, 1:-1] * (f[1:-1, 1:-1] - f[1:-1, :-2])
```

which gives the same result, given u>0

I was thinking to use `m = ma.masked_array(u, (u > 0)).mask` somehow, but by indexing like `f[m]` I get only a 1D array, so I get the 2D structure lose. Is there a more Pythonic way to carry out this iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two operations can be seen as a single [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), just  shifted depending on the sign of `u`:

```
x = np.zeros_like(f)
d = np.diff(f, axis=1)
x[:, 1:-1] = np.where(u[:, 1:-1]>0, d[:, :-1], d[:, 1:])
```

*NB. you can replace `:` on the first axis in all slicings by `1:-1` to really match your loop.*

Output:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,  10,  12,   8,  10, -50,   0],
       [  0,  11,  11,  11,  11,  11,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

---

the exact conditional that matches your loop is:

```
x[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.where(u[1:-1, 1:-1]>0,
                         u[1:-1, 1:-1]*(f[1:-1, 1:-1]-f[1:-1, :-2]),
                        -u[1:-1, 1:-1]*(f[1:-1, 2:]-f[1:-1, 1:-1]))
```

Comment: although my expression is a bit more complex, this could be the solution.

Comment: @MichaelW I added the conditional that matches your loop if this helps to generalize. I prefer the `diff` approach for the current operation though ;)

Comment: Also note that there is no real conditional in numpy, all values are calculated, then numpy choses which one to take based on the boolean values. Therefore, I'd expect the `diff` to be faster since the subtraction is only performed once.

Comment: Consider `x = np.where(y > 0,  y,  y*1000)`. It seems for me, that the multiplication operation is carried out for the whole array, because y*1000 is passed as a parameter. If there are only a few y <=0, thn there are a lot of unnecessary operations. I wanted to speed up calculation time, but it seems that this doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelW that's what I explained in my last comment. However, performing unnecessary operations in numpy is often faster than try to avoid them with conditions. Depending on your exact operation, you can try to minimize the unnecessary computations by only using the conditional on the step that needs it. Another possibility is to use a loop with `numba`. Which is faster will depend on the exact data/operation and size of the arrays.

Comment: I understand...the reason for asking was to reduce unnecessary operations and to speed up.

Comment: see follow up topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687260/why-is-my-sliced-array-variant-in-python-slower-as-compared-with-the-element-wis

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use `np.ndenumerate` to "walk" through your multi-dimensional array `u` so you'll have just one level of `for`.

See the docs at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate