# Why is my sliced array variant in Python slower as compared with the element-wise operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77683855/can-i-use-a-more-pythonic-way-for-my-conditional-array-operations), which has already a good answer; but there were unnecessary operations identified (see discussion in the posting) and I was just curious if I could succeed in eliminate them...

In the meantime, I found a method which avoids unnecessary multiplications (using masks for indexing) and gives the same result. The code is below.

Variant 1 is the original.

In Variant 2 I tried to make use of python slicing combined with masking - not only to write the two loops in a better and more compact way, but mainly in the hope it would get faster. But it turned out, that it is even slower by ~30%. To be honest, the original code is more readable, but I was hoping to get significant improvement as compared to the double-loop.

Why is this not the case?

Or asked the other way around: In which situations are slice operations faster as compared to element-wise operations? Are they just syntactic sugar with significant internal overhead? I thought that they are implemented in C/C++ under the hood and must be faster than manual looping over `i,j` in Python.

The output:

```
D:\python\animation>python test.py
used time for variant 1: 1.0377624034881592
used time for variant 2: 1.30381441116333

D:\python\animation>python test.py
used time for variant 1: 0.8954949378967285
used time for variant 2: 1.251044750213623

D:\python\animation>python test.py
used time for variant 1: 0.9750621318817139
used time for variant 2: 1.3896379470825195
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import time


def test():

 
    f = np.array([
        [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,      0], 
        [0,   1,   3,   6 ,  4,   2,      0], 
        [0,   2,   4,   7 ,  6,   4,      0],    
        [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,      0]
        ])
        

    u = np.array([
        [0,   0,    0,    0,   0,   0,     0], 
        [0,   0.5,  1,    0,  -1,  -0.5,   0], 
        [0,   0.7,  1.1,  0,  -1,  -0.4,   0], 
        [0,   0,    0,    0,   0,   0,     0], 
        ])
        
    
    # calculate : variant 1
    x = np.zeros_like(f)
    
    maxcount = 100000
    
    start = time.time()

    for count in range(maxcount):
        for i in range(1,u.shape[0]-1):
            for j in range(1,u.shape[1]-1):
                if u[i,j] > 0: 
                    x[i,j] = u[i,j]*(f[i,j]-f[i,j-1])
                else:
                    x[i,j] = u[i,j]*(f[i,j+1]-f[i,j])
                
    end = time.time()
    print("used time for variant 1:", end-start)
                
                           
    
    # calculate : variant 2

    y = np.zeros_like(f)  

    
    start = time.time()
    
    for count in range(maxcount):
        maskl = (u[1:-1, 1:-1] > 0)
        maskr = ~maskl 
        diff = f[1:-1, 1:]  - f[1:-1, 0:-1]
        
        (y[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskl]  = (u[1:-1, 1:-1 ])[maskl]  * (diff[:, :-1])[maskl]
        (y[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskr]  = (u[1:-1, 1:-1 ])[maskr]  * (diff[:, 1: ])[maskr]
    
    end = time.time()
    print("used time for variant 2:", end-start)
    
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(x, y)


test()
```

"Pre-fetching" slices for u and y makes it a bit better, but not significantly:

```
    for count in range(maxcount):
        maskl = (u[1:-1, 1:-1] > 0)
        maskr = ~maskl 
        diff = f[1:-1, 1:]  - f[1:-1, 0:-1]
        
        yy = (y[1:-1, 1:-1])   # <<-- 
        uu = (u[1:-1, 1:-1 ])  # <<--
        
        yy[maskl]  = uu[maskl]  * (diff[:, :-1])[maskl]
        yy[maskr]  = uu[maskr]  * (diff[:, 1: ])[maskr]
```

Comment: Your arrays are relatively small.  In such a  case often the iterative version is faster.  But the vectorized scales much better.  For example if I expand your arrays to (400,700), the vectorized version is 50x faster.

Comment: OK - good and important hint :-)

Comment: I should also point out there's a bug in your program. Since `f` is an integer array, so is `x` (and `y`).  You probably want them to be double arrays.

Comment: yes, ... that's true. Anyway, I will try it

Comment: Using double, variant-2 is also much much faster. But thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite getting the same answer as you, probably because I'm using floating point arrays instead of integer arrays (or I have a bug in my program), but you might find something like this a little simpler:

```
        temp = np.zeros_like(f, )
        temp[:,1:] = f[:,:-1]  # temp[a, b] = f[a, b - 1]
        x1 = u * (f - temp)
        temp[:,:-1] = f[:,1:]  # temp[a, b] = f[a, b + 1]
        x2 = u * (temp - f)
        result = np.where(u > 0, x1, x2)
```

I think this is a little bit clearer about your intent, and doesn't involve lots of masking.

Comment: Your method gives same result and is even faster: 

        D:\python\animation>python test.py
        used time for variant 1: 10.822681903839111
        used time for variant 2: 0.2043442726135254
        used time for variant 3: 0.11795234680175781
        t1/t2: 52.96298137167739
        t1/t3: 91.75469753076437

Comment: I understand your solution. But I was wondering, whether some useless operations are calculated: x1 and x2 are calculated without looking at u>0 and only at the end, the relevant elements from x1 and x2 are taken. Nevertheless, your variant is even faster. Interesting...Obviously the useless calculations don't matter as compared to the masking overhead.

Comment: I'm letting Numpy do what Numpy does best: perform vector operations.  The arrays `f`, `temp`, and `u` are all standard contiguous arrays and so operations are fast.  The cost performing the useless operations is less than the cost of avoiding them.

Comment: p.s.  As an experiment, you might want to get rid of the multiplication by `u` in the calculation of `x1` and `x2` and add it to `result = u * ....`.   Probably a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily speed-up the process with [numba](/questions/tagged/numba). Also, as stated in the comments, it depends how big are your input arrays - with bigger arrays the second variant becomes faster.

Here is quick benchmark:

```py
import perfplot

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


def variant_1(u, f):
    x = np.zeros_like(f)

    for i in range(1, u.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(1, u.shape[1] - 1):
            if u[i, j] > 0:
                x[i, j] = u[i, j] * (f[i, j] - f[i, j - 1])
            else:
                x[i, j] = u[i, j] * (f[i, j + 1] - f[i, j])

    return x


def variant_2(u, f):
    y = np.zeros_like(f)

    maskl = u[1:-1, 1:-1] > 0
    maskr = ~maskl
    diff = f[1:-1, 1:] - f[1:-1, 0:-1]

    (y[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskl] = (u[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskl] * (diff[:, :-1])[maskl]
    (y[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskr] = (u[1:-1, 1:-1])[maskr] * (diff[:, 1:])[maskr]

    return y


@njit
def variant_numba(u, f):
    x = np.zeros_like(f)

    for i in range(1, u.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(1, u.shape[1] - 1):
            if u[i, j] > 0:
                x[i, j] = u[i, j] * (f[i, j] - f[i, j - 1])
            else:
                x[i, j] = u[i, j] * (f[i, j + 1] - f[i, j])

    return x


f = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
)

u = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0.5, 1, 0, -1, -0.5, 0],
        [0, 0.7, 1.1, 0, -1, -0.4, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
)

x1 = variant_1(u, f)
x2 = variant_2(u, f)
x3 = variant_numba(u, f)

assert np.allclose(x1, x2)
assert np.allclose(x1, x3)


def setup_u_f(n):
    return np.tile(u, (n, n)), np.tile(f, (n, n))


perfplot.show(
    setup=setup_u_f,
    kernels=[
        lambda u, f: variant_1(u, f),
        lambda u, f: variant_2(u, f),
        lambda u, f: variant_numba(u, f),
    ],
    labels=["variant_1", "variant_2", "variant_numba"],
    n_range=[1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
    xlabel="np.tile(_, (n, n))",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Creates this graph:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know what numba is. Thanks for the hint and the code example how to use it.